# draw overlay on a map

Tags: cocoa-touch

How to draw an overlay on the mapview?

Answer (score 1):

See a [discussion](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=484975) on MacRumors. 
Brief version: use [iphone-google-maps-component](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-google-maps-component/) as a way around not being able to overlay on the mapview.

Basically iphone-google-maps-component is:

> A component that you can add to your iPhone application to access all basic features of Google Maps (similar to Android's MapView). It uses a UIWebView in the background to load the HTML/Javascript version of Google Maps, and offers a set of Objective-C methods that mimic a subset of the original Javascript methods for controlling the map. It currently supports setting the center location and zooming & panning using the touch interface. You can see it in action